# how to change the text in the bootstrap context menu after row is expanded?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, contextmenu

I am using [boostrap context menu](https://github.com/dgoguerra/bootstrap-menu). I have a table when I right click on a row it is expanding and showing additional information below the row using ajax.

Please see the demo4 [here](https://dgoguerra.github.io/bootstrap-menu/demos.html#demo4). If you right click to the 2nd row you will see the text "set editable" while the other rows have a different text in the menu. I am trying to achieve the same thing. If the row is right clicked again after my row is expanded I need a text "collapse" to be shown and all other rows which are not expanded should show a text "expand" in the menu. When my row is expanded the tr ellement is getting extra class `shown`.

I tried to create 2 menus hoping it would show a text "collapse" on other menu but it only  took the last BootstrapMenu function into account.

```
var menu = new BootstrapMenu('#Table tbody tr', {
 actions: {
 showdetails: {
 name: 'Expand',
 iconClass: 'fa-compress',
 ....... 
 .....
 ...
var menu = new BootstrapMenu('#Table tbody tr.shown', {
 actions: {
 hidedetails: {
 name: 'Collapse',
 iconClass: 'fa-compress',
 ....... 
 .....
 ...
```

I didn't understand the usage of below code. I have too many rows anyway.I am not sure how to do this. I would appreciate if you can show me how show a "collapse" text.

```
  '1': { name: 'First row', isEditable: true, isRemovable: true },
  '2': { name: 'Second row', isEditable: true, isRemovable: true },
  '3': { name: 'Third row', isEditable: true, isRemovable: true }
```